# How to take data from mysql db and insert them into a wx.ComboBox with mysqldb in Python

Tags: python, wxpython, mysql-python

I create a panel in wxpython, plus i have a database(MySQLdb), then i select some data from my database and i want to insert them in a wx.Combobox(dropdown), after that if the choice is A choice or B choice i want to insert some other data from database in a listbox.The code is below:

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import wx

APP_SIZE_X = 661
APP_SIZE_Y = 319

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, wx.DefaultPosition, 
        size=(APP_SIZE_X, APP_SIZE_Y))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1,style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

        sel="Make your choice"
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1,sel,(15,10))

            db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",use_unicode="True",
                    charset="utf-8",
        user="youruser",passwd="somepwd",db="choicedb")

        cursor=db.cursor()
        sql="""SELECT name from choicetb"""

        cursor.execute(sql)

        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in rows:

                  print row[1]



            sampleList = ["A choice", "B choice", "C choice"]#The data from db
            wx.ComboBox(panel, -1, "A choice", (15, 30), 
            wx.DefaultSize,sampleList, wx.CB_DROPDOWN)

        math="Selected items"
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1,math,(10,100))

        listBox = wx.ListBox(panel, -1, (10, 130), (230, 120),
        ' ', wx.LB_SINGLE)


        exitbutton =wx.Button(panel,-1, label="Quit", pos=(300, 230))
        exitbutton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit)
        self.Centre()

    def OnQuit(self, e):

        self.Close()

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'form1.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

How i insert what choice i take from row in combobox, i try something but it gives me the last choice of course. I know is something inside for loop but what? Thanks for your answers and for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the new data into a Python list and then use the ListBox's / ComboBox's AppendItems(your_list) method. That's probably the easiest way. If you already have a list for the combobox, you could do something like this:

```
self.myComboList = ["some", "list"]
for row in rows:
   self.myComboList.Append(row[1])
self.ComboList.sort()
self.myComboBoxWidget.AppendItems(self.ComboList)
```

Something like that should work.